# Is it possible to set up email forwarding for sent items?

Tags: email, imap, forwarding

I have created a catchall email address (record@domain.com) and added a forwarder for all other domain email accounts to this address. All incoming email are correctly routed to record@domain.com, but emails sent from the domain email addresses do not appear in the sent items for record@domain.com.

Is it possible to configure it that way - having all sent emails for all accounts stored in the main catchall forwarding address sent items for the domain?

I searched for this on the hosting company's control panel and online, but could not find any solution, so my thinking is that it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Usually sent messages are only stored by the client (uploaded via IMAP), so they get stored only in the same account as they're sent from.

"Catch-all" storing by the server itself is not impossible; there are several ways to implement it – some servers can store all saved messages to a folder, others can force a "Bcc:" recipient to be automatically added to all outgoing messages.

So if you own the entire server (i.e. administrator access to the OS), it might be doable if you bypassed the control panel and configured the underlying software directly. (Usually the server runs something like Postfix to handle mail, which has `sender_bcc_maps`.)

However, most "mail+web" hosting providers do not have such a feature at all.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @grawity ! That gives me something to work on.